# Insert into with multi select or multi conditions

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that contains many informations:

```
 CREATE TABLE sequences (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` TEXT NULL,enter code here    
    `nbrlsu` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nbrits` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nbrco1` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nbrrcbl` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nbrmatk` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nbrsequences` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,   
    `parent_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
        );
```

I want to create a table based on sum of columns in the first table
for exemple I want to know te number of elements that have the same parent_id and has numbersequences>0
and I want to know for each type of sequences the number of rows that contains information:

```
SELECT parent_id ,
       Classification,count(id) as nbrspecies,
       SUM(nbrsequences) ,
       SUM(nbrco1),
       SUM(nbrits),
       SUM(nbrlsu),
       SUM(nbrrcbl),
       SUM(nbrmatk)  
FROM dashboard_specimen 
GROUP BY parent_id
```

and I have an other kind of queries:

```
SELECT parent_id ,
       count(id) as co1  
FROM dashboard_specimen 
WHERE nbrco1>0     
GROUP BY parent_id ;
```

and

```
SELECT parent_id ,
       count(id) as nbrspecies  
FROM dashboard_specimen 
WHERE nbrsequences>0 
GROUP BY parent_id
```

and other types like this
and my goal in the end is to insert this information into an other table with insert select
like this:

```
INSERT INTO bold_namestats (id,
                            name,
                            numberofstrains, 
                            numberofsequences,
                            numberofco1,
                            numberofits,
                            numberoflsu,
                            numberofrbcl,
                            numberofmatk)
SELECT parent_id ,
       Classification,
       count(id) as nbrspecies,
       SUM(nbrsequences) ,
       SUM(nbrco1),
       SUM(nbrits),
       SUM(nbrlsu),
       SUM(nbrrcbl),
       SUM(nbrmatk)  
FROM dashboard_specimen 
GROUP BY parent_id
```

I don't know if there is a simple way to do this with temp tables or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have resolved my problem using join and temp tables

```
INSERT INTO bold_namestats (_id,numberofstrains, numberofsequences,numberofco1,numberofits,numberoflsu,numberofrbcl,numberofmatk,numberstrainswithco1,numberstrainswithseq) 
SELECT a._id ,a.numberofstrains,a.numberofsequences ,a.numberofco1,a.numberofits,a.numberoflsu,a.numberofrbcl,a.numberofmatk,b.numberofstrainswithco1,c.numberofstrainswithseq  FROM bold_temp_namestats a    left join bold_strainswithco1 b on a._id=b.parent_id left join bold_strainswithseq c on a._id=c.parent_id union 
SELECT a._id ,a.numberofstrains,a.numberofsequences ,a.numberofco1,a.numberofits,a.numberoflsu,a.numberofrbcl,a.numberofmatk,b.numberofstrainswithco1,c.numberofstrainswithseq   FROM bold_temp_namestats a    right join bold_strainswithco1 b on a._id=b.parent_id left join bold_strainswithseq c on a._id=c.parent_id ;
```

this query is used to replace full outer join so I fill 3 tables with data and after that I insert with joinin result with left and right join and union the result to get full lines in the end

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you could do a subquery for each column you want to populate, filtering each subquery for an id.

```
INSERT INTO bold_namestats (id,
                            name,
                            numberofstrains, 
                            numberofsequences,
                            numberofco1,
                            numberofits,
                            numberoflsu,
                            numberofrbcl,
                            numberofmatk)
select parent_id, (*select1* where parent_id=...), (*select2*  where parent_id=...), ... , (*selectn*  where parent_id=...)
from dashboard_specimen
group by parent_id
```

where ***select1***, ***select2***, ... , ***selectn*** are the different queries you have.

Comment: my problem is that I have in the first look every query is with group by so I the number of line for numberofsequences is not the same as the number of matk so the first one has 10 000 lines and the second one has 300. I can't use this solution.I have tryed using temp tables but with temp tables joins I can't show all lines

Comment: I have created 3 temp tables and I wanted to insert informations directly:INSERT INTO bold_namestats (id,numberofstrains, numberofsequences,numberofco1,numberofits,numberoflsu,numberofrbcl,numberofmatk,numberstrainswithseq,numberstrainswithco1)
SELECT a._id ,a.numberofstrains,a.numberofsequences ,a.numberofco1,a.numberofits,a.numberoflsu,a.numberofrbcl,a.numberofmatk,c.numberofstrainswithseq,b.numberofstrainswithco1  FROM bold_temp_namestats a,bold_strainswithco1 b,bold_strainswithseq c where a._id=b.parent_id and a._id=c.parent_id .But the result is not all rows containing informations.